# How do I do an F-test to compare nested linear models in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I want to compare two nested linear models, call them m01, and m02 where m01 is the reduced model and m02 is the full model. I want to do a simple F-test to see if the full model adds significant utility over the reduced model.

This is very simple in R. For example:

```
mtcars <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/focods/WonderfulML/master/data/mtcars.csv")
m01 <- lm(mpg ~ am + wt, mtcars)
m02 <- lm(mpg ~ am + am:wt, mtcars)
anova(m01, m02)
```

Gives me the following output:

[image]

Which tells me that adding the **am: wt** interaction term significantly improves the model. Is there a way to do something similar to this in Python/sklearn/statsmodels?

**Edit:** I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243802/how-do-i-do-an-f-test-to-compare-nested-linear-models-in-python) before posting this one and can not figure out how they are the same.  The other question is doing an F-test on two vectors.  This question is about comparing 2 nested linear models.

I think this is what I need:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression

but am not sure what exactly to pass this function.  If anyone could provide or point to an example, that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You can try sklearn.model_selection http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection

from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression

Comment: the duplicate mark is incorrect. As mentioned in the edit, these are two different f-tests.

Comment: for the answer, see statsmodels anova_lm http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/anova.html to compare nested models, OLS results also has three compare_xxx_test methods for direct testing of a nested restricted against the unrestricted model. http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.html

Comment: @user333700 Thanks.  Just need to get familiar with this style of formula syntax.  Looks similar to what R uses on the surface.

Comment: @Mr_U4913 Thanks.  I looked at that link and haven't ruled it out yet, but I just want to compare sets of 2 nested models at a time like I show in my example.  The model_selection is doing way more than I need.

Comment: f_regression is the function u want

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adapting Jeremy's answer in the following way allowed me to get the same result I obtained in R:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from statsmodels.stats.anova import anova_lm

cars_df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/focods/WonderfulML/master/data/mtcars.csv")
m01 = ols('mpg ~ am + wt', data=cars_df).fit()
m02 = ols('mpg ~ am + wt + am:wt', data=cars_df).fit()
anovaResults = anova_lm(m01, m02)
print(anovaResults)
```

This gave me the following results in my jupyter notebook:

[image]

I also got these rather cryptic errors:

[image]

Anyone have a clue as to what is generating these errors?

Comment: This would be better as a new question. brief answer: you can ignore those warnings. The F-value is and is supposed to be nan, but recently numpy and scipy have started to issue warnings for nans in the distributions.

Answer (score 5):

I found this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZBi1DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=python%20anova_lm%20f%20test&source=bl&ots=48vV9WRQ9L&sig=esH__XxBZHlFIRWaXbpVJ1j-Uv4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb5drZ28TXAhWERiYKHSnkCVsQ6AEIVTAH#v=onepage&q=python%20anova_lm%20f%20test&f=true) helpful ("An introduction to statistics with python" / Thomas Haslwanter)

Here is the relevant code sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from statsmodels.stats.anova import anova_lm

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value', 'treatment'])
model = ols('value ~ C(treatment)', data=df).fit()
anovaResults = anova_lm(model)
print(anovaResults)
```

Look at the book link above for the print result.

Note: [anova_lm](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.anova.anova_lm.html) sometimes used with the parameter 'typ', try its different possible values to see which suitable for you.

Comment: +1 for the reference.  This was a different kind of ANOVA, but I was able to make some small adjustments to this example to get the same results.